# How to quantitatively evaluate the impacts of each variables on the measured data

Tags: multiple-regression

I am trying to evaluate the individual effects of A,B,C,D on Result. A and B are numerical variable and C, d are categorial.

Could anyone give me some suggestions about what statistical method to use? I was thinking about the meta-analysis, but found that there is no control group.

I will appreciate your suggestions!

```
A   B   C   D   n  Result s.d.
2.5 3.2 S   A   5   20      2
1.7 2.6 S   A   3   31      3
3.2 5.2 S   B   4   41      3
4.4 6.1 L   B   6   52      2
5.2 7.2 L   A   3   41      5
9.2 8.8 L   B   5   62      3
9.5 8.9 L   B   3   67      1
```

Comment: in R, if your data frame is called df, then simply do 
anova(lm(Result ~ A+B+C+D, data=df)).

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst, thank you very much for your suggestion!